# Can't run tensorflow on Win10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run Gpt2 on my machine, i am following this guide : https://lambdalabs.com/blog/run-openais-new-gpt-2-text-generator-code-with-your-gpu/

I created a new environment on Conda to make sure it would be isolated and all, and downloaded the correct versions of the libs.

My environment is :

Windows 10
Python 3.6
tensorflow-gpu 1.12 (installed with `pip`)
CUDA v9, v10, v11
cuDNN for v9 and for v11 (i first installe dht elatest, but then i was told tensorflow was only happy with version 9 so i installed it)

Whenever i try to import tensorflow, either with `from tensorflow import *` or `import tensorflow as tf`

I get  :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Anaconda3\envs\gpt2\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

This error isn't helping at all, and i'm stuck there. Any ideas ?

Thank you.

EDIT :

For those running in the same problem, follow the github link, install everything with conda. I also ran into this problem : [Tensorflow has no Attribute "sort" in GPT 2 Git Release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510865/tensorflow-has-no-attribute-sort-in-gpt-2-git-release) that was solved as well by udating tensorflow. Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you add Cuda and Cudnn version as well as how you installed TensorFlow?

Comment: @AniketBote i added it. I have cuda 9, 10 and 11 with the cuDNN lib for the version 9 and 11

Comment: Try to install the `tensorflow` using `conda`, not `pip`. Also, refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors), and your error listed at the bottom of the list.

Comment: check this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794

Comment: @HùngNguyễn oh my god thank you it looks exactly like my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to install tensorflow with conda with below command.

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow   //tensorflow package
```

or for specific version

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.13.1
```

Comment: correct. installing with conda was the correct way (?). Bu ti must add that @HùngNguyễn 's link was also very helpful